# How to use multiple HTML buttons in CSS and display the value in a text input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get multiple values of the buttons displayed next to each other in "field2" when you select them. I could not find out how to combine them in a working way...

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("field2").value = document.getElementById("field1").value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=1 onclick="myFunction()">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=2 onclick="myFunction()">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=3 onclick="myFunction()"><br>
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=4 onclick="myFunction()"> .....
  <br> Code: <input type="text" id="field2"><br><br>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique, you shouldn't use the same `field1` for all the buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure what "in CSS" means here, but the passing of an identifying property to a function is fundamental in programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a unique ID for each HTML element for the ID selector to work properly in Javascript.  You can also pass in `this` to your function call, which will refer to the HTML element being interacted with.

I've modified your snippet, with the result textbox with `id="result"`.  Additionally in `myFunction`, you need to concatenate (`+=`) the old string value with the new value.

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  document.getElementById("result").value += el.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=1 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field2" value=2 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field3" value=3 onclick="myFunction(this)"><br>
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field4" value=4 onclick="myFunction(this)"> .....
  <br> Code: <input type="text" id="result"><br><br>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling myfunction from the button as they are pressed.
Something like this :

```js
function myFunction(button) {
  var field2 = document.getElementById("field2");
  field2.value += button.value;
}
```

```html
<input class="calculator" type="button" value="1" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<input class="calculator" type="button" value="2" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<input class="calculator" type="button" value="3" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<input class="calculator" type="button" value="4" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<br> Code: <input type="text" id="field2"><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` as the argument to the function, so it can access the button that was clicked.

Use `+=` to append to the value instead of overwriting it, so you get all the buttons that were clicked.

```js
function myFunction(button) {
  document.getElementById("field2").value += button.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=1 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=2 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=3 onclick="myFunction(this)"><br>
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=4 onclick="myFunction(this)"> .....
  <br> Code: <input type="text" id="field2"><br><br>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use the same ID for multiple elements, as IDs are meant to be unique on a page. You can select the elements by class instead.
2. It is better to attach the event listeners with `addEventListener` rather than using inline event handlers.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  document.getElementById("field2").value += e.target.value;
}
document.querySelectorAll('.calculator')
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', myFunction));
```

```html
<input class="calculator" type="button" value=1>
<input class="calculator" type="button" value=2>
<input class="calculator" type="button" value=3><br>
<input class="calculator" type="button" value=4> .....
<br> Code: <input type="text" id="field2"><br><br>
```